# Is there a way to dynamically modify the properties (e.g. fontsize, color) of the kivy spinner dropdown list?

Tags: python, kivy

I am looking for a way to dynamically change the properties such as color and font size of the dropdown list items that are shown within my Kivy spinner widget.  I learned that one can use option_cls to set up these things, but I can't figure out how to change them when my app is running.

I have attached an example of my app, which consists of a Button to change color, a Label showing the color with the newly changed color, and a Spinner with a dropdown list. I can change the text color of the spinner without problem (*my_spinner.color*), but I can't change the text color of the dropdown list at all. Even if I changed *my_spinner.option_cls.color*, the text in the dropdown list remains to be the same color. I suspect this is related to the fact that the SpinnerOption is a separate object. Is there a way to do this?  Thanks!

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from random import random

Builder.load_string('''
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
#:import random random

<MySpinnerOption@SpinnerOption>:
    height: 90
    font_size: dp(13)
    color: [1,1,1,1]

<RootBox>:
    Spinner:
        id: my_spinner
        size_hint: (0.5, 0.25)
        font_size: dp(15)
        color: [1,1,1,1]
        background_color: [1,1,1,1]
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
        values: ['Hi', 'I', 'am', 'your', 'spinner']
        text: 'Please select'
        option_cls: Factory.MySpinnerOption
    Button:
        id: color_button
        text: 'Change Color'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y': 0.25}
        size_hint: (0.5, 0.075)
        color: [1,1,1,1]
        on_press: root.color_array = [random.random() for _ in range(3)] + [1]
    Label:
        id: color_label
        text: 'Color: {:.2f},{:.2f},{:.2f}'.format(*root.color_array[:3])
''')


class RootBox(BoxLayout):
    color_array = ListProperty([0,0,0,0.5])

    def on_color_array(self, *args):
        print(self.color_array)
        #These two work without problem
        self.ids.color_label.color = self.color_array
        self.ids.my_spinner.color = self.color_array

        #This doesn't work
        self.ids.my_spinner.option_cls.color = self.color_array


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return RootBox()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `kv` includes a rule for building instances of `MySpinnerOption`, so that rule will always be applied. The resulting `color` will always be `[1,1,1,1]'.

You can accomplish what you want by removing the `<MySpinnerOption@SpinnerOption>:` rule and specifying the `option_cls` as a string. Then specifying the `color` attribute using a class level attribute of the `MySpinnerOption` class. Here is a modified version of your code that does this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.spinner import SpinnerOption
from kivy.properties import ListProperty

class MySpinnerOption(SpinnerOption):
    my_font_color = [1,1,1,1]  # this is a class attribute, not an instance attribute
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.height = 90
        self.font_size = dp(13)
        self.color = self.my_font_color  # use the class attribute for the font color
        super(MySpinnerOption, self).__init__(**kwargs)

Builder.load_string('''
#:import random random

<RootBox>:
    Spinner:
        id: my_spinner
        size_hint: (0.5, 0.25)
        font_size: dp(15)
        color: [1,1,1,1]
        background_color: [1,1,1,1]
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
        values: ['Hi', 'I', 'am', 'your', 'spinner']
        text: 'Please select'
        option_cls: 'MySpinnerOption'
    Button:
        id: color_button
        text: 'Change Color'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y': 0.25}
        size_hint: (0.5, 0.075)
        color: [1,1,1,1]
        on_press: root.color_array = [random.random() for _ in range(3)] + [1]
    Label:
        id: color_label
        text: 'Color: {:.2f},{:.2f},{:.2f}'.format(*root.color_array[:3])
''')


class RootBox(BoxLayout):
    color_array = ListProperty([0,0,0,0.5])

    def on_color_array(self, *args):
        print(self.color_array)
        #These two work without problem
        self.ids.color_label.color = self.color_array
        self.ids.my_spinner.color = self.color_array

        #This works
        MySpinnerOption.my_font_color = self.color_array  # change the class attribute

        # trigger rebuild of dropdown by changing option_cls
        self.ids.my_spinner.option_cls = 'SpinnerOption'
        self.ids.my_spinner.option_cls = 'MySpinnerOption'


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return RootBox()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Works like a charm. You are brilliant, thanks a lot!  I tried to define everything in python and did the option_cls = MySpinnerOption, but what I couldn't figure out was the two lines to change option_cls again to trigger the rebuild of the dropdown.